# Cron not sending wp-mail()

Tags: php, wp-cron, wp-mail, cron

I have a problem with a cron schedule function, it does not want to send an email with the `wp_mail()` function.

**This is my code:**

It is placed in the functions.php

```php
<?php

    add_filter('cron_schedules', 'add_review_invites_schedule');
    function add_review_invites_schedule($schedules){
        $schedules['send_review_invites_interval'] = array(
                'interval' => 5*60,
                'display' => __('Every Five Minutes'),
        );
        return $schedules;
    }

   if (!wp_get_schedule('send_review_invites_event')) {
       wp_schedule_event( time(), 'send_review_invites_interval', 'send_review_invites_event');
   }

   add_action( 'send_review_invites_event', 'send_review_invites' );

   function send_review_invites(){
       echo 'test';
       wp_mail( 'me@example.com', 'Automatic email', 'Automatic scheduled email from WordPress to test cron');
   }

?>
```

Some things you should know I have connected the wp-cron to my server cron so it runs this code on my website. I have also put `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', false);` in the wp-config.php.

The output I get in my mail when the server cron runs, echos  `test`. This shows me that the function `send_review_invites()` is being run. Yet somehow I don't get another email on the email address given in the `wp_mail()` function.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: is your server correctly configured to send emails?

Comment: @Vishwa yes, it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test if mail has been sent or not using the following:

```
// Set $to as the email you want to send the test to.
$to = "you@yoursite.com";

// Email subject and body text.
$subject = 'wp_mail function test';
$message = 'This is a test of the wp_mail function: wp_mail is working.woo!';
$headers = '';

// Load WP components, no themes.
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-load.php');

// send test message using wp_mail function.
$sent_message = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

//display message based on the result.
if ( $sent_message ) {
    // The message was sent.
    echo 'The test message was sent. Check your email inbox.';
} 
else {
    // The message was not sent.
    echo 'The message was not sent!';
}
```

Check whether your server is configured correctly to send emails, which `wp_mail()` requires. When in doubt, you can also try using SMTP to confirm it. By using the SMTP method, if it delivers the mail then your problem is with your mailserver.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Vishwa answer you could log the `wp_mail()` function according to this link: [Wordpress reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)

```
add_action('wp_mail_failed', 'log_mailer_errors', 10, 1);
function log_mailer_errors( $wp_error ){
  $fn = ABSPATH . '/mail.log'; // say you've got a mail.log file in your server root
  $fp = fopen($fn, 'a');
  fputs($fp, "Mailer Error: " . $wp_error->get_error_message() ."\n");
  fclose($fp);
}
```